# Problems with defining popper options

Tags: javascript, electron, popper.js

I am currently having problems preventing my tooltips from leaving the view.

This is my code for creating the Tooltip instance:

```
// The '+'-Button as seen on the screenshots below
const btn = document.getElementById('tooltip-btn')

new Tooltip(btn, {
    title: 'Add new product',
    trigger: 'hover',
    popperOptions: {
        modifiers: {
            // Docs even say that this is enabled by default
            preventOverflow: { enabled: true }
        }
    }
})
```

With or without passing an `popperOptions` object, the tooltip is still leaving the view to the left.

How it looks like right now:

[image: How it look even with passing on my popperObject]

How I want it to look:

[image: How I want it to look]

Am I doing something wrong while creating the tooltip or am I missing a popper / tooltip option?

Current npm versions of both modules are:
`"popper.js": "^1.15.0", "tooltip.js": "^1.3.2"`

Any help is highly appreciated and if you need more information, don't hesitate to ask. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try `placement: 'top', // or bottom, left, right, and variations` as seen on the [documentation](https://popper.js.org/tooltip-examples.html) ... and `preventverflow` will be `preventoverflow`

Comment: @chrispbacon setting the placement param does not seem to have any effect on my overflowing problem. Thanks for pointing out the typo, sadly it had no effect on my problem :(

Comment: ah ok. It looked a bit like it's more a positioning issue

Answer (score 0):

Try the offset settings

```js
let btn = document.querySelector("button")
new Tooltip(btn, {
  title: 'Add new product',
  trigger: 'hover',
  placement: "left-end",
  offset:"100,100",
  popperOptions: {
    modifiers: {
      offset: {
        enabled: true,
      }
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tooltip.js"></script>
<button class="button">Hover Me</button>
```